# Access asp.net web application from lan computers

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a system(Server) with windows server 2008 and over 5 system as client systems.
Visual studio 2008 installed on every system (Server and Client).
And i have installed IIS-7 on server.I need to access my asp.net web project from server to client system using visual studio 2008.When i use file system to open that project from my local system it through error:

> network BIOS command limit has been reached

Can any one tell me how to access asp.net web project from client system

Comment: Can you provide more detail on what you're trying to do when you say you "need to access my asp.net web project from server to client system using visual studio 2008" - do you mean debug it in the web browser, edit the live application (presumably uncompiled) on the server using Visual Studio, or publish?

Comment: Yes i need to do the same thing.
I am having an asp.net web project on my local server.
And i am trying to debug that project from my network connected another system from visual studio 2008.
My project size on disk is about 150 mb.
When i am trying to execute a small project (up-to 50 mb disk size)
it works fine.When the size of project increases at that time it troughs error  
>network BIOS command limit has been reached
I am just trying to use(and update) my web project from network sheared drive.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend you keep a local development copy on your development workstations, using some kind of source control system (such as Team Foundation Service, GitHub) to keep them all in sync and manage changes. Team Foundation Service is free for up to five users. Doing changes directly against a live system is bad practice, and trying to debug over a network is generally not going to work all that well (at best it is going to be slow). Source control will also allow you to roll back any changes that causes problems or recover accidentally lost/overwritten code.

Answer (score 0):

After installing windows-7 on client system.
This problem is solved.
Now i am able to debug my web project from LAN computers.